# Blackberry - ListField with images from filesystem

Tags: image, graphics, blackberry, file-io

I use the following code to retrieve image from the phone or SDCard and I use that image in to my ListField. It gives the output but it takes very Long time to produce the screen. How to solve this problem ?? Can any one help me?? Thanks in advance!!!

```
String text = fileholder.getFileName();
try{
 String path="file:///"+fileholder.getPath()+text;
 //path=”file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/image.bmp”

 InputStream inputStream = null;
 //Get File Connection
 FileConnection fileConnection = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path);

 inputStream = fileConnection.openInputStream();

 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 int j = 0;
 while((j=inputStream.read()) != -1) {
 baos.write(j);
 }
 byte data[] = baos.toByteArray();                
 inputStream.close();
 fileConnection.close();  

 //Encode and Resize image 
 EncodedImage  eImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data,0,data.length);
 int scaleFactorX = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getWidth()), 
      Fixed32.toFP(180));
 int scaleFactorY = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getHeight()), 
      Fixed32.toFP(180));
 eImage=eImage.scaleImage32(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
 Bitmap bitmapImage = eImage.getBitmap();  
 graphics.drawBitmap(0, y+1, 40, 40,bitmapImage, 0, 0);
 graphics.drawText(text, 25, y,0,width);
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read files once (on App start or before screen open, maybe put a progress dialog there), put images in array and use this array in paint.